# how to crop the detected face image in opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

I detected the face in the image using opencv 2.4.10 in java

I put my face detection code.

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    int x,y,height,width;

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    //CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector=new CascadeClassifier();
    faceDetector.load("C:/opencv-2.4.10/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    //System.out.println(""+faceDetector);
   // Mat image = Highgui .imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("D:/shekar.jpg").getPath());
    Mat image = Highgui .imread("D:/Eclipse - New Juno/New Juno Projects/detectface/man1.jpg");
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }
    String filename = "china.jpg";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);


}
```

}

Now i want to crop the detected face and save it as new jpg image in opencv java.

Crop code is

```
 Rect rectCrop = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
 Mat image_roi = image(rectCrop);
        image_roi.copyTo(cropimage);
        imwrite("cropimage.jpg",image_roi);
```

The error is

The method image(Rect) is undefined for the type FaceDetector
The method imwrite(String, Mat) is undefined for the type FaceDetector

Please anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import static org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imwrite;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {
    private static Mat cropImage;

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    int x = 0,y = 0,height = 0,width = 0;

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

//CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xm    l").getPath());
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(Snapshot.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
Mat image = Highgui.imread("C:\\image.jpg");

faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, face_Detections);
System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces",  face_Detections.toArray().length));

Rect rect_Crop=null;
for (Rect rect : face_Detections.toArray()) {
    Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
            new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}
       
 Mat image_roi = new Mat(image,rectCrop);
  Highgui.imwrite("C:\\cropimage_912.jpg",image_roi);

}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dhvani its work well. i have done it by another way. the method is                                                                                  Mat crop=new Mat();
        crop=srcImg.submat(y,height,x,width);
      Highgui.imwrite("screen3.jpg", crop);

Comment: A few changes in opencv :                                                        Highgui.imwrite() ---> Imgcodecs.imwrite();                                              Core.rectangle() ---> Imgproc.rectangle();

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV has region of interest functions which you may find useful. If you are using the cv::Mat then you could use something like the following.

```
// Take your Final Detected Image
image;

// These values need to be your determined face rect values
cv::Rect myROI(x, y,width, height);

// Crop the full image to that image contained by the rectangle myROI
// Note that this doesn't copy the data
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);
```

Comment: Thanks  @ GPPK.  i have edit my code by please see my edited code. Its also has som error on image(rectCrop)

Comment: I am not using cv::Mat.  Could you help to solve this in another way... Thanks for your response @ GPPk

Answer (score 2):

how to crop multiple faces? dhvani.

```
for (Rect rect : face_Detections.toArray()) {
    Core.rectangle(
        image,
        new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
        new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
        new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

Mat image_roi = new Mat(image,rectCrop);
    Highgui.imwrite("C:\\cropimage_912.jpg",image_roi);
}}
```

Comment: to crop multiple faces

Comment: do u know to crop multiple faces?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this. This one works just fine.**

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetection
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);


        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier();

 faceDetector.load("D:\\OpenCv\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        System.out.println ( "Working" );
        // Input image
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\input.jpg");

        // Detecting faces
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        // Creating a rectangular box showing faces detected
        Rect rectCrop=null;
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
        {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
             new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                           new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        }

        // Saving the output image
        String filename = "Ouput.jpg";
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\"+filename, image);

        Mat markedImage = new Mat(image,rectCrop);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("D:\\cropimage.jpg",markedImage );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int detectedFaces = faceDetections.toArray().length;
        Rect rect_Crop=null;

        // Draw a bounding box around each face.
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x
                    + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            rect_Crop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);


            Mat image_roi = new Mat(image,rect_Crop);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("outputimage");
            sb.append(detectedFaces).append(".jpg");
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(sb.toString(),image_roi);
            detectedFaces--;
        }
```

This is for people asking how to crop multiple faces with openCV java.

Comment: consider explaining your code so people can understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
 Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
        Rect rect = facesArray[i];
        Imgproc.rectangle(frame, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        Mat submat = frame.submat(facesArray[i]);
        imwrite("./face" + i + ".jpg", submat);
    }
```

This looks like the smartest way to do it .